# Jenkins shows same information for all projects

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I've been using Jenkins for the last month or so and what started out as a small issue has gotten worse and worse. I have 10 projects in Jenkins, all polling from different Git repos and building to different environments but they all show the same details on the dashboard.

[image: Image of the issue]
I can still build the projects, but I have to manually enter the URL to see any console output etc.

I'm running 1.536 under Ubuntu 12.04, there's not much in the logs other than the following;

```
Oct 22, 2013 2:21:19 PM WARNING jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap search JENKINS-15652 Assertion error #1: failing to load /data/builds #20 EXACT: lo=23,hi=9,size=23,size2=23 –
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How have you setup Jenkins? Does it run under Windows or Unix? What version? Do you use an application server? Is there anything in the log files? ....

Comment: I set it up via aptitude under Ubuntu 12.04. Current version is 1.536, though I've just updated to this I had the same issue on the previous version. No application server.

The only thing in the logs are a few lines of the following;

`Oct 22, 2013 2:21:19 PM WARNING jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap search
JENKINS-15652 Assertion error #1: failing to load /data/builds #20 EXACT: lo=23,hi=9,size=23,size2=23`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by clearing out my build directory.

Comment: And here is the actual Jenkins issue for it (one of several). https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18289